# How to emit a signal from the pyqt5 groupbox that can be updated dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-signals

I have the parallel thread that read 10 uart and prints the data in pyqt5 gui. But the issue I am facing is those groupbox get updated when all 10 jobs completed but not instantly.

EDIT: To achieve parallelism I am using joblib not pyqt thread.

What I want to achieve is change the state of groubox attributes such as a label, pushbutton text, and colour but I don't find a good example how to trigger a signal emit for the groupbox.

Do I need to emit the individual label, buttons in the groubox or I can emit as one groupbox object?

This is a minimalistic code, where it has just two groupbx. Can someone help how to emit the signal from groubox and catch that change, i.e the state of label, button text, and colour in the below code?

Below example update the groubox without any issue but in real each g1 method is uart and it's blocking call. I wait till all jobs to complete to see the changes on my GUI.

Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    changedValue = pyqtSignal(int)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 140, 120, 141))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 80, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 140, 120, 141))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.groupBox.update)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.groupBox_2.update)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "UART1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test1"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IMEI"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "UART2"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test1"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test2"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IMEI"))

        #Setting a connection here
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.g1)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.g2)

    def g1(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Running"))
        imei = "12345"
        self.label.setText(imei)
        self.changedValue.emit(imei)
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pass"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FAIL"))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(0, 255, 0);")

    def g2(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Done"))
        imei = "12345"
        self.label_2.setText("12345")
        self.changedValue.emit(imei)
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FAIL"))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pass"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I recommend you read [Using the Generated Code](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) from the docs. PyQt in this post recommends not modifying the code generated by Qt Designer since it is not a widget it is only a class that is used to fill a widget, instead it is better to create another class based on the chosen form and implement the logic there, since for example your code has a serious error: the signals can only be created in a QObject like the widgets but Ui_MainWindow is not.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 140, 120, 141))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 80, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 140, 120, 141))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.groupBox.update)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.groupBox_2.update)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "UART1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test1"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IMEI"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "UART2"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test1"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test2"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IMEI"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    changedValue = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #Setting a connection here
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.g1)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.g2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def g1(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Running"))
        imei = "12345"
        self.label.setText(imei)
        self.changedValue.emit(imei)
        self.pushButton_2.setText("Pass")
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FAIL"))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(0, 255, 0);")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def g2(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Done"))
        imei = "12345"
        self.label_2.setText("12345")
        self.changedValue.emit(imei)
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FAIL"))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pass"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Amazing, this is what I want. Your pyqt hero. I got clear now QT designer created is not Widget.

Comment: @danglingpointer On the other hand QThread does not run in parallel, I recommend you check information about the different types of concurrency. QThread implements multithreading. multithreading and parallelism are 2 types of concurrency